# Error with Twitter link

Tags: facebook, twitter

Yesterday I started a new app on Facebook. Today I got the message that when people copy the link to Twitter they get an error. This is what you get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /your_namespace:your_action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

What does this mean? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually sending the POST action link to Twitter? Why?

I think you misunderstood how Open Graph works. Basically, you should be the one publishing actions when users take an action using your service. You can use a server-side or a client-side language to POST request (when you click a link, your browser actually makes a GET request, not a POST) to https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:action?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&OBJECT_PATH=OBJECT_URL

Note that you need to create an app, use it to authenticate users to get the access token and also set your custom actions / objects. These will need to be approved before you can actually use them.

You should start by taking a look at the sample apps to see how they work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/